CONFLICT after rebase when file deleted in remote branch (master)
I have a branch that needs to be rebased onto master since there is a change in master. Basically, one of the header files has been deleted and some of its contents moved to another unit (split between a new header/spurce file). The job seems pretty clean - just rebase my branch onto remote master:
git rebase origin/master

This however, creates the main issue - one file in master has been deleted, and I still have it in my branch. Here is the output:
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: checkin name...
Usind index info to reconstruct a base tree...
A   filename1
M   filename2
M   filename3
.
.
.
waring: squelched 60 whitespace errors
warning: 65 lines add whitespace errors
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge ...
Auto-merging file1
Auto-merging file2
Auto-merging file3
Auto-merging file4
CONFLICT (modify/delete): fileheader1.h deleted in HEAD and     modified in ... Version ... of fileheader1.h left int tree.
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 ...
The copy of the patch failed is found in:
/home/wsluser/tempo/test/Engine/.git/rebase-apply/patch
When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git     rebase --abort".

So in order to resolve this conflict, I did the following:
git rm fileheader1.h

And the resulting output was:
fileheader1.h needs merge rm 'fileheader1.h'

The file is gone from the folder; all seem happy, but there is another issue:
git rebase --continue

shows another conflict:
Applying: ....... .. .. Using index info to reconstruct a base tree ... M .vscode/settings.json Failed to merge in the changes. Patch failed at 0004 ...
which I resolved manually and marked it as done:
git add .vscode/settings.json

Then:
git rebase --continue
And finally, it seems all was fine:
Applying ...

Then the final push with:
git push --force origin branchname

And here comes the fun part:
error: src refspec branchname does not match any. 
error: failed to     push some refs to 'git@...../reponame.git'

My understanding of this message is that it shall appear when one tries to commit/push changes to a branch that does not exist. However, in this case, it is not the case; the branch exists and is very real. How can I solve this problem?

So you don't actually have any issues with resolving merge conflicts, but with using git push.


This however, creates the main issue - one file in master has been deleted, and I still have it in my branch

No, that's not the issue. The issue is that the file in master was deleted and you edited it in your branch.
So to avoid that problem, don't edit it in your branch.
Let's start over:

Using the reflog, undo your entire rebase.
Now restore that file to its state before you edited it.
Finally, do not rebase; that was a lousy idea. Just fetch and then merge origin/master into your branch. Now any remaining conflicts will be much easier to resolve and there's no need for force pushing later.


But why did this cause the error when pushing?

@mkrieger1 Maybe the repeated foodly-doodly during the rebase caused the OP to fall off the branch in some way — I've no idea. The OP did not faithfully report everything they said to Git and everything Git said in reply, so it would just be guessing.

Well, I have not edited the file in my sandbox. Actually the sequence was: git clone repolocation.git then git checkout branchname and then git rebase origin/master. I haven't edited this file locally hence my confusion. So how can I rectify the issue if no edit was done locally? Cheers

Git said: "deleted in HEAD and modified in [your commit]". I believe Git.
